# Query timeout - A Task was canceled

Tags: .net

I suspect I am getting a timeout running a query but I am not sure how to increase the timeout

The query is retrieving about 17,000 records (40 columns per record)

My .NET code is as follows:-

```
      try
        {
            //create auth client to retrieve token
            var auth = new AuthenticationClient();

            //get back URL and token
            await auth.UsernamePasswordAsync(consumerkey, consumersecret, username, password);

            instanceUrl = auth.InstanceUrl;
            accessToken = auth.AccessToken;
            apiVersion = auth.ApiVersion;

            var client = new ForceClient(instanceUrl, accessToken, apiVersion);


            //Toolkit handles all serialization
            string query = @"select col1"
                        + ",col2"
                        + ",col3"
                        + ",...."
                        + ",...."
                        + ",col40"
                        + " from Account";


            var accounts= new List<Account>();

            var results = await client.QueryAsync<Account>(query); 
            var totalSize = results.TotalSize; 

            Console.WriteLine("Queried " + totalSize + " records.");

            account.AddRange(results.Records); 
            var nextRecordsUrl = results.NextRecordsUrl; 


            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextRecordsUrl)) 
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("Found nextRecordsUrl."); 

                while (true) 
                {
                    var continuationResults = await client.QueryContinuationAsync<Account>(nextRecordsUrl); 
                    totalSize = continuationResults.TotalSize; 
                    Console.WriteLine("Queried an additional " + totalSize + " records.");

                    accounts.AddRange(continuationResults.Records); 
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(continuationResults.NextRecordsUrl)) break; 

                    //pass nextRecordsUrl back to client.QueryAsync to request next set of records 
                    nextRecordsUrl = continuationResults.NextRecordsUrl; 
                } 
            } 

            //loop through returned accounts
            foreach (Account a in accounts)
            {
                DataAccess.ImportAccount(a);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.ToString());
        }
```

How can I increase the timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per solution provided in this link you can use this.

> To solve this try to use ORDER BY ID also in the query.
>
> For e.g. ORDER BY Id LIMIT 1000 works to fetch the data efficiently.
>
> This is due to an optimization introduced at the Database level that
>   takes advantage of the fact that IDs are ordered.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000171421&language=en_US

Comment: Sure - but if I do that I will only ever return 1000 records and not be able to loop through retrieving everything I need

Comment: It is not mandatory to use LIMIT here....You can go with only ORDER BY ID. You can use batch apex also if you have large amount of data. http://blog.shivanathd.com/2013/01/how-to-write-batch-class-in.html

Comment: Yes, how stupid of me. I'll remove the LIMIT and also check out the batch stuff and report back

Comment: If this works for you can select as answer so that other people can get help from it. :)

Comment: The order by ID definitely helped with the speed, thanks